# Reading netCDF data

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, netcdf

I am trying to read data from a `nc` file, which has the following variables:

```
['latitude', 
'longitude', 
'latitude_bnds', 
'longitude_bnds', 
'time', 
'minimum', 
'maximum', 
'average', 
'stddev', 
'AirTemperature']
```

What I am trying to achieve is to extract the `AirTemperature` data for any given `(time, latitude and longitude)`:

And for that, I am doing something like this:

```
df = Dataset('data_file.nc', 'r')   
lat = df.variables['latitude'][:]
lon = df.variables['longitude'][:]
temp = df.variables['AirTemperature'][:,:,:]

#(lat, lon) for Coffee, TN
test_lat = 35.45
test_lon = -86.05

#getting the indices for the (lat, lon) using numpy.where
lat_idx = np.where(lat==test_lat)[0][0]
lon_idx = np.where(lon==test_lon)[0][0]

#extracting data for all the times for given indices
tmp_crd = temp[:,lat_idx,lon_idx]
```

Up till this point, it all goes fine. However, when I print the data, I see all the identical values being printed.. (for any lat, lon that I have been testing..)

```
print tmp_crd.data
>>> [-9999. -9999. -9999. ..., -9999. -9999. -9999.]
```

Which I don't seem to understand..why the air temperature is always shown as -9999.0? I have tested for a lot of other (lat, lon) points, and it seems for every location point, the air temperature is -9999.0. How can I extract the real data from this file?

Please help :-(.

Thank You

Comment: Use `h5dump` to print the actual contents of your HDF5 data store to confirm the contents of the air temperature array.

Comment: from the terminal directly? like `h5dump data_file.nc` ?

Comment: gives an error: `h5dump error: unable to open file "data_file.nc"`

Comment: I tried to read using ncdump...shows a lot of data, which looks correct too (like real values). I researched, and found that the -9999.0 must be the `fill_value` of the numpy masked array. But how come I see too much data there in ncdump and almost nothing when I run using the python's netcdf4?

Comment: You'll need to either (1) post your actual data file for us to use, or (2) dig into the data itself, and see what is happening step by step.  You haven't shown us for example what the row you want looks like, what the indexes you get are, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay..I think I figured out. Here is what was happening:

The `nc` file i have has a different precision for latitude and longitudes, and I was apparently passing much more rounded sets of `(lat, lon)` points. Once I figured out the right precision, it works fine for me. The `-9999.0` value was basically the `_fill_value` for the numpy's masked array (which indicated that if there is no record matching the given set of lat and long, return the masked values).

Thanks every one.