# How to add daily values of carbon emission stored in NETCDF4 files using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, netcdf4

The netcdf4 file contains a daily carbon emission for a specific month that covers the whole globe ( each grid is 0.1 degrees x 0.1 degrees) and there are 31 days to this month.
Is there a way to add up all the daily values(ndays) and save a new netcdf4 file that stores the global value of each sector's monthly emission？

```
%matplotlib inline

import xarray as xr

import cartopy.crs as ccrs

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import pandas as pd

dset = xr.open_dataset(carbon_data)

print(dset)

print(dset['emission'])
```

After running the following code, I get the result as

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (latitude: 1800, longitude: 3600, nday: 31)
```

Coordinates:

- latitude   (latitude) float64 89.95 89.85 89.75 ... -89.75 -89.85 -89.95
- longitude  (longitude) float64 -179.9 -179.8 -179.8 ... 179.7 179.8 179.9
  Dimensions without coordinates: nday
  Data variables:
  emission   (nday, latitude, longitude) float64 ...

<xarray.DataArray 'emission' (nday: 31, latitude: 1800, longitude: 3600)>
[200880000 values with dtype=float64]

Coordinates:

- latitude   (latitude) float64 89.95 89.85 89.75 ... -89.75 -89.85 -89.95
- longitude  (longitude) float64 -179.9 -179.8 -179.8 ... 179.7 179.8 179.9
  Dimensions without coordinates: nday
  Attributes:
  units:    kgC/h

Thank you so much.

Comment: Take a look at [netCDF4](https://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading netCDF data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34012184/reading-netcdf-data)